# Get short-lived public URL for files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am writing a web app that helps people manage their facebook pages. One of the features required is the ability to send files to Facebook users from the application. There can be many sources for the file, like the hard-drive, OneDrive, Google Drive etc. OneDrive provides a short lived public download URL for a file. They have mentioned it [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v72/js-picker-open.htm) in their JavaScript file picker example. I can use this url in Facebook Messenger's file upload API to send it to the Facebook user. But I couldn't find such an option in Google Drive docs.

Is there any way to get such a public URL for a file from Google Drive, so that I can pass it as the file reference in Messenger's upload file API. I am using Google Drive's JavaScript Picker in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation from [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/picker).

> If you want to let users open or upload Google Drive files directly
>   from your web app independently of the Drive UI, you can use the
>   Google Picker API. The picker can display a list of the currently
>   authenticated user's Drive files in an interface like the following:

Check also the [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) for an in depth guide.

> This documentation is intended for developers who wish to add Google
>   Picker API to their pages. A basic level of JavaScript fluency is
>   required.
>
> Read through this document to see code samples for common scenarios.

or,

you can try using [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) to get the desired downloadUrl.